# how to use parent constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop

please help solve the problem. i have base class 'Unit':

```
var Unit = function() { 
  this.x_coord = x_coord;
  this.y_coord = y_coord;
  this.color = color;
};
```

and child class 'playerUnit':

```
var playerUnit = function(gameObj, x_coord, y_coord, color) { 
  Unit.apply(this, arguments);
};

playerUnit.prototype = Object.create(Unit.prototype);

var Game = function(options) {
  new playerUnit(this,1,1,'red');  
};

var app = new Game();
```

I plan in the future to do a lot of these child classes: 'enemyUnit', 'tankUnit', 'boatUnit', etc. and i need use common properties: x_coord, y_coord, color.

```
i try use Unit.apply(this, arguments);
```

but after start script i have in console follow error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: x_coord is not defined

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vzk73qah/2/

Comment: Your parent constructor does not have any parameters defined. It wouldn't work if you only did `new Unit(…)` either, this has nothing to do with your child class (which is fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the parameters in `Unit`:

```
var Unit = function(gameObj, x_coord, y_coord, color) { 
  // ...
};
```

Also consider passing an object to avoid repeating these parameters in all functions.

```
var Unit = function(data) { 
  this.x_coord = data.x_coord;
  this.y_coord = data.y_coord;
  this.color = data.color;
};
var playerUnit = function(data) { 
  Unit.call(this, data);
};
new playerUnit({
  gameObj: this,
  x_coord: 1,
  y_coord: 1,
  color: 'red'
});
```

Comment: `Unit` doesn't use `gameObj`. But this is a close-as-typo question.